# Split and wrap string with html tag base on character length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have bunch of string and would like to split and wrap them with html tag. I created a small example but my attempt has failed:

http://jsbin.com/taweparota/1/edit?html,js,output

```
var str = '0123456789';
str = str.split('');

var temp = '';
for ( var i = 0; i < str.length; i++ )
{
  if(i === 0){
    temp += '<div>'+str[i]+'</div>';
  }else if(i % 3 == 0){
    temp += '<div>'+str[i]+'</div>';
  }else{
    temp += str[i];
  }

}

console.log(temp);
```

My expected output will be
012345 and so on. And the group by 2 can be change, like i can change the length of the content i want to 3 and the loop still work. I don't know why my above attempt failed, need help.

Comment: Do you want output to be `012` or `<div>0</div><div>1</div><div>0</div>`?

Comment: Do you want <div>0</div>12<div>3</div>45<div>6</div> and so on??? Your question is not clear. if you done any format in the required output, let me know

Comment: <div>012</div><div>345</div> etc

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
var result = '0123456789'.match(/.{1,2}/g)
                         .map(i => '<div>' + i + '</div>')
                         .join('');

console.log(result);
```

If you want to change your grouping to 3:

```js
var result = '0123456789'.match(/.{1,3}/g)
                         .map(i => '<div>' + i + '</div>')
                         .join('');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this function is broken, what if my content is abcde not 1234? the source can be anything.

Comment: @AntonioJordan It will still work with `abcde` or any other content. It would not hurt to try before you call my code "broken".